# Why doesn't updating my list trigger a re-render of my component?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, render

Given the code below I would expect to see a new list item added to the  when I click the button. The state data appears to be updated but the DOM does not change. I confess to being quite a newbie with React and Hooks so hopefully this is just a question of me not understanding the binding model in play here.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [someList, setSomeList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() =>
    {
      const someDataForTheList = [1,2,3];
      setSomeList(someDataForTheList);
    }, []);

  const onClickAddToList = () =>
      {
        let newDataForTheList = someList;
        newDataForTheList.push(someList.length + 1);

        setSomeList(newDataForTheList);

        console.log(someList);
      }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>{someList ? someList.length : null}</h1>
        <ul>
          {someList ? someList.map((i) =>
              <li key={i}>
                {i}
              </li>)
              : null}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={onClickAddToList}>Add to list</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because react does not do deep inspection when checking for updates (by default). So pushing a new item on the same list and then assigning it again using the hook's dispatch method React determines this to be the same object/item, thus concluding the view does not have to be updated.

You can however do the following:

```js
const onClickAddToList = () => {
  // creating a new list
  const newDataForTheList = [...someList, someList.length + 1];
  setSomeList(newDataForTheList)
}
```